# How to show Azure DevOps wiki attachment that has been created by API

Tags: azure, api, devops, attachment, wiki

If I edit an existing Azure DevOps wiki page and click on the **Insert a file** icon to add files Pic1.png, Pic2.png, Pic3.png, I see that the returned path for each is (N.B. I've deliberately added the space between **]** and **(** so it shows correctly here)

![Pic1.png] (/.attachments/Pic1-**5d8168e5-b287-433e-91e0-17b5581f486a**.png)

![Pic1.png] (/.attachments/Pic2-**408decae-ab26-4b68-80d2-8d53f9f15cba**.png)

![Pic1.png] (/.attachments/Pic3-**dd225b4f-4f1d-4644-80e9-057787d5264d**.png)

Where do the **bold** guids come from?

I want to do this all via the API via a C# desktop app. I create a wiki page and put the placeholder for attachments in the correct positions as

![Pic1.png] (/.attachments/Pic1.png)

![Pic2.png] (/.attachments/Pic2.png)

![Pic3.png] (/.attachments/Pic3.png)

then attach the files (images).

But ... they only show as broken images because they're missing the guid part.

There doesn't seem to be an API call to List attachments, so how can I get the guid?

Or am I doing this incorrectly and there's a better way to do it?

Comment: Please consider tagging this `azure-devops-wiki`. I would have done it but there is a five tag limit and I did not want to remove any of your tags.

Answer (score 1):

This suddenly doesn't seem to be an issue any more - I'm guessing that Microsoft have made a change on their end, because the guids are no longer there. Thus the response I get from the attachfile API call is of the form

![Pic1.png] (/.attachments/Pic1.png)

and that is what I use in the body of the wiki page.

It all works now.